# ace python mode single letter local variables why does not prompt autocomplete

Tags: javascript, python, ace-editor

[image]
The variables n and nn, a and aa are defined as shown in the figure, why does it only prompt nn and aa to be local when typing a or n below, and why n and a are not prompted?

Is there a way to prompt n and a for autocomplete at the same time when you type n or a?

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. The idea of auto complete is to... well, auto complete what you type. `n` doesn't have `a` in it.

Comment: @Guy If I type `a` the `a local` maybe should in the prompt list?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this editor, I'm guessing the creator decided to exclude the names that are already typed from the list.

Comment: If you'd like to view single-letter auto-completion items, press Ctrl+Space without typing a prefix to open the auto-completer.